# What are the hidden achievements in Loop Hero?

Tags: achievements, loop-hero

In Steam, I can see that there are currently 5 hidden achievements remaining on my version of Loop Hero.

[image: 5 hidden achievements steam screenshot]

What are all the hidden achievements, and how do you earn them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The eight hidden achievements are:

1. Just Starting Out, Defeat the lich
2. Punching Bag, Defeat the lich three times
3. Glass Queen, Defeat the Priestess
4. Faith Alone is not enough, Defeat the Priestess three times
5. For whom the horn tolls.., Defeat the Hunter
6. Hunter's Nightmare, Defeat the Hunter three times
7. Memory Pieces, Defeat the Omega
8. Godslayer, Defeat the Omega six times

Comment: Interesting - I have Just Starting Out, Glass Queen, and For whom the horn tolls, but it still says "5 hidden achievements remaining". Could there be an eighth?

Comment: Defeating the hunter three times has one as well -- 'Hunter's Nightmare'.